# is there any ETC1 texture compression library?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am trying to convert a texture (RGBA32) to ETC1 format, and i need that to happen in runtime. is there any C/C++ library that could do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [rg-etc1](http://code.google.com/p/rg-etc1/) library. Also you can take source from Google Android project - clone this GIT repo [frameworks/base.git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git) and take `opengl/include/ETC1/etc1.h` and `opengl/libs/ETC1/etc1.cpp` files.

Comment: `etc1.h` and `etc1.cpp` are now under [frameworks/native](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/). I've just spent several hours searching for them, leaving this here so someone else doesn't have to. ;)

Answer (score -3):

FFmpeg is right library.. [Link](http://ffmpeg.org/)